# Treeview problems in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I've table in database ItemList that hold ProdutID with ItemID.

```
ProductID    ItemID
  AAA         1001
  AAA         1002
  AAA         1003
  BBB         1201
  BBB         1293
  CCC         1040
  DDD         2011
  DDD         3203
```

I want add all those data to Treeview Like this:

```
+AAA
 - 1001
 - 1002
 - 1003
+BBB
 - 1201
 - 1293
+CCC
 - 1040
+DDD
 - 2011
 - 3203
```

please teach me how to do this. Thanks.

edit :

i try to add each item into ArrayList with length 2 data (ProductID, ItemID)

```
   for(int i=0;i<arrayList.count;i++)
    {
       TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(((string[])arrayList[i])[0]);    
       treeview1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?  What have you tried?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart 

currently i tried to add all items in ArrayList.
then

for (int i= 0;i <arrayList.count;i++)
{
TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(((string[])arrayList[i])[0]);
treeview1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
}

then i've no idea how to add child for every product. -_-"

Comment: It's best to edit your question when providing more information. Code doesn't go in comments.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal we dont use that anymore, the aim is not to roadblock people's questions. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TreeGridNode nodeParent = treeGridView1.Nodes.Add("AAA");

TreeGridNode nodeChild = nodeParent.Nodes.Add("1001"); 
TreeGridNode nodeChild = nodeParent.Nodes.Add("1002"); 
TreeGridNode nodeChild = nodeParent.Nodes.Add("1003");
```

You would do this dynamically using two for loops

```
foreach (var product in Products)
{
  TreeGridNode nodeParent = treeGridView1.Nodes.Add(product.Id);
  foreach (var item in product.Items)
  {
   TreeGridNode nodeChild = nodeParent.Nodes.Add(item.Id); 
  }

}
```